# How to Authorize Swagger to use MS Graph API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger-ui, azure-ad-graph-api, nswag

We are building a Web API wrapper for MS Graph API.

I want to use Swagger to test my APIs. But I can't get the configuration right. I keep getting Bad Request and no other clue. I can't install Fiddler or other tools on this corporate laptop to help me investigate.

Here is the Error
[image]

And here is the code to configure Swagger:

```
app.UseSwaggerUi3WithApiExplorer(settings =>
{
    settings.GeneratorSettings.DefaultPropertyNameHandling = PropertyNameHandling.CamelCase;
    settings.PostProcess = document =>
    {
        document.Info.Title = "App title";
        document.Info.Description = "App description";
    };

    settings.OAuth2Client = new OAuth2ClientSettings
    {
        ClientId = [clientid]
        ClientSecret = [clientsecret]
        AppName = "app_name",
    };
    settings.OAuth2Client.AdditionalQueryStringParameters.Add("response_type", "code id_token");
    settings.OAuth2Client.AdditionalQueryStringParameters.Add("nonce", "AnyValueShouldBeRandom");

    settings.GeneratorSettings.DocumentProcessors.Add(new SecurityDefinitionAppender("Auth Token", new SwaggerSecurityScheme
    {
        Type = SwaggerSecuritySchemeType.OpenIdConnect,
        Description = "Swagger OAuth2",
        OpenIdConnectUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/[tenantid]/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration",
        Flow = SwaggerOAuth2Flow.Implicit,
        AuthorizationUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/[tenantid]/oauth2/v2.0/authorize",
        TokenUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/[tenantid]/oauth2/v2.0/token",
        In = SwaggerSecurityApiKeyLocation.Header,

        Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "api://[api]/user_impersonation", "" },
            { "user.read", "" },
            { "openid", "" },
            { "email", "" },
            { "profile", "" },
            { "roles", "" }
        }
    }));

    settings.GeneratorSettings.OperationProcessors.Add(new OperationSecurityScopeProcessor("oauth2"));

});
```

My question is what am I doing wrong?

I have been struggling with this since this morning. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

### UPDATE 3/21/2019

I figured it out.

change this from

```
Type = SwaggerSecuritySchemeType.OpenIdConnect
```

to

```
Type = SwaggerSecuritySchemeType.OAuth2
```

I also removed a bunch of stuff like the ff lines

```
settings.OAuth2Client.AdditionalQueryStringParameters.Add("response_type", "code id_token");
settings.OAuth2Client.AdditionalQueryStringParameters.Add("nonce", "AnyValueShouldBeRandom");
```

It's now working.

At least on the outside.

Swagger tells me I am already Authenticated:

[image]

BUT when I run the application, *HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated* tells me I'm not.

Same question: What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Be sure to register your app in the right app regristration portal if using the v2 endpoint.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I did, in fact, and I missed to mention in the question that, I am successfully redirected to the MS login screen.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I can answer my own question.

I'm not going to be too hard on myself this time because the fix was not very obvious, at least to me.

Apparently,

```
settings.GeneratorSettings.OperationProcessors
```

should have a matching

```
settings.GeneratorSettings.DocumentProcessors
```

It's partly my fault if I didn't google hard enough or the docs really wasn't that accessible.

But this line

```
settings.GeneratorSettings.OperationProcessors.Add(new OperationSecurityScopeProcessor("oauth2"));
```

Needs a match. So replace the following

```
settings.GeneratorSettings.DocumentProcessors.Add(new SecurityDefinitionAppender("Auth Token", new SwaggerSecurityScheme
```

with

```
settings.GeneratorSettings.DocumentProcessors.Add(new SecurityDefinitionAppender("oauth2", new SwaggerSecurityScheme
```

I hope this helps somebody else.

Comment: Please update the nswag wiki if it is not clear enough and it gives value to othrr users